# Spring Boot test with one transactional datasource reading uncommited data from the other

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I have following problem while writing a test case using multiple datasources.

In datasource (1) I like to prepare data.

In datasource (2) I like to import the data from (1).

Now I have the problem that the whole thing is @Transactional. The result is, that I can't insert the data from (2) because the data from (1) are no yet commited.

Reduced code example:

```
@Test
@Transactional    
public void importTest(){
    jdbcTemplateDs1.update("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL) VALUES ('TEST")');
    jdbcTemplateDs2.update("INSERT INTO OTHERTABLE (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE@DATASOURCE1 WHERE col = 'TEST)");
    //results in 0 because the first statement wasn't commited yet
    jdbcTemplateDs2.queryForList("SELECT * FROM OTHERTABLE").size()
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth would you try to do something like this.

Comment: Good question. It's a kind of necessary synchronization between two databases.
Probably the better question would be: How do I build two transactions, each on on another datasource, so that the first transaction commits but does a roleback when the second one fails.

Comment: You might be looking at distributed transactions or replication, or a different approach altogether (hard to suggest exactly, since it's unclear what your real goal is), but nothing that you should be writing by hand the way you're doing in your example.